# unable to access wp-admin after change default theme on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I installed a theme in my `wp-admin` and selected it as the default theme without configuration.

After that I removed it from `c-panel`; my site is fine, but I cant get in to my `wp-admin` because it says:

```
The theme directory "theme" does not exist.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other themes on your `wp-content/themes` folder? (Twenty Seventeen for example) If so, which ones?

Comment: yes i have other theme in that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the deleted theme files with you ?

You can upload the theme back into the theme directory and login into your dashboard then change your theme from the admin. After that, you can delete your theme.

If you do not have the theme files with you, you will need to reinstall wordpress.

Comment: i did it it does not work now i have 500 internal server error

Comment: Have you uploaded the "unzipped" theme files into the theme folder ? Have you changed anything in htaccess or database ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you delete the active theme and wordpress can't loading it.

You have to select another theme for work properly.

Let me know.

Comment: yes i deleted the active theme from c-panel but now i have only 1 theme and i cant go to my dashboard to select another theme

Comment: For solve it you can restores the old theme that you have deleted (upload theme folder by cpanel or FPT and activate it). Select the theme you want active and delete the theme the old theme.